# Interface, Abstract Class and Methods of Abstract Class

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class, late-binding

I am learning how to use the **Factory pattern** for creating objects in Java. I want to create classes to manage Cars. A car can either be small or large. I created an interface that defines the methods to be implemented by an implementing class. An abstract class implements some of the common methods of the interface shared by small and large cars. The concrete SmallCar and LargeCar classes implement the remaining methods of the abstract class.

**THE CAR INTERFACE**

```
public interface Car {
 String getRegistrationNumber();
 void drive();
}
```

**THE ABSTRACT CAR CLASS IMPLEMENTS CAR INTERFACE**

```
public abstract class AbstractCar implements Car { 
 private final RegistrationNumber regNumber;
 private boolean tankFull = true;

 public AbstractCar(RegistrationNumber regNumber) {
  this.regNumber = regNumber;
 }

 @Override
 public final String getregistrationNumber() {
  return regNumber.toString();
 }

/**This method is not defined in the implemented Car interface. I added it to
*the abstract class because I want subclasses of these abstract class
*to have this method*/
 public boolean isTankFull() {
  return tankFull;
 }
}
```

**SMALL CAR EXTENDS ABSTRACT CLASS**

```
public final class SmallCar extends AbstractCar {
 public SmallCar(RegistrationNumber regNum) {
  super(regNum);
 }

 @Override
 public void drive() {
  //implemented here
 }
}
```

**FACTORY CLASS**:

**This class is responsible for creating instances of a particular type of car.**

```
public final class CarFactory {
 public static Car createCar(String carType, RegistrationNumber regNum) {
  Car car = null;
  if (carType.equals("Small") {
   car = new SmallCar(regNum);
  }
  return car;                
}
```

**MAIN METHOD**

```
RegistrationNumber regNum = new RegistrationNumber('a', 1234);
Car c = CarFactory.createCar("Small", regNum);

c.getRegistrationNumber(); //this works
c.isTankFull(); //this instance of Car cannot access the isTankFull method defined on the abstract class. The method is not defined on the Car interface though. I do not understand why.
```

The challenge is that the instance of Car can access every other method defined on the Car interface but it cannot access the `isTankFull()` method defined on the abstract class but not defined on the interface. I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: Nothing strange here.  Put isTankFull on the interface.

Comment: You need to cast your instance to an AbstractCar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't see the method there is because your `c` object is declared as a `Car` interface. Granted, when it comes out of your factory method, it is a `SmallCar`, but your variable there is only the interface. You could either change your declaration to `AbstractCar c = CarFactory.createCar("SmallCar", regnum);`.

Another way you could accomplish this while working with the interface would be to cast your `c` object to an `AbstractCar` when trying to access methods that are not on the interface, however you need to be careful as there is always the possibility that your factory could return an object that implements `Car`, but not `AbstractCar`.

```
if (c instanceof AbstractCar) {
    ((AbstarctCar)c).isTankFull();
}
```

Of course, the other easy solution would be to add the method to the interface, though that would remove the teaching opportunity from this question.

Comment: Also, be careful when you cast the instance returned from the factory because the factory could possibly return some instance of Car which is not derived from AbstractCar.

Comment: Good point. I'll clarify that. Casting it was an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

The good solution is to put your `isTankFull()` on the interface. It makes sense as any car implementing `Car` would need access to `isTankFull()`.

The question is: are you creating any `Car` that will not be able to answer the question `isTankFull`? If so, then moving `isTankFull` to the interface will not make sense.

Another solution (if you don't want your `isTankFull()` to be on the interface), is to cast your `Car` to the appropriate type:

```
if (c instanceof AbstractCar) {
    ((AbstractCar)c).isTankFull();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a contract (or a protocol) that you made with the users of the classes that implement it. So you have to ask to yourself if **any** `Car` should expose the information `isTankFull` (i.e. should respond to message `isTankFull`). If the answer is 'yes', then the method `isTankFull` must be added to the interface.

Looking at your code, it seems that the class `AbstractCar` is only a *utility* class. Then, the method `isTankFull` should be lift up to interface, or it should be made at least `protected`.

On the other hand you have to ask yourself if your client code, i.e. main method, really needs a generic `Car`, or if it needs instead a specific kind of car, such as a `SmallCar`.

Finally, rember that the use of interface lets you minimize dependency between your components.